# How do you eager load data via Alias in Fetch method?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections, fluent-nhibernate, eager-loading

Ok so I have the following relationships:

Bulletin < BulletinEmailLog < BulletinEmailLogRecipient - Contact - Entity

Where the "<" stands for 1 to many and the "-" is one to one.

And here is the code:

```
BulletinEmailLog BulletinEmailLogs = null;
        BulletinEmailRecipient EmailRecipients = null;
        Contact Contact = null;
        Entity Entity = null;
        var pastBulletin = NHibernateSession.Current.QueryOver<Bulletin>()
                        .Where(x => x.Id == bulletinID)
                        .Fetch(x => x.BulletinEmailLogs).Eager
                        .JoinAlias(x => x.BulletinEmailLogs, () => BulletinEmailLogs, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                        .JoinAlias(() => BulletinEmailLogs.Recipients, () => EmailRecipients, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                        .JoinAlias(() => EmailRecipients.Contact, () => Contact, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                        .JoinAlias(() => Contact.Entity, () => Entity, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                        .Future<Bulletin>();
```

Here I try to use one database query to grab all of the necessary information. 
The problem , is that later I try to loop through the BulletinEmailLogs but I see a call to the database. I would like to be able to add eager loading statements within the preceding code in order to do later searches using memory. Is that possible?

Comment: When you see the calls to the database, are you sure it's populating the "BulletinEmailLogs", and not other parts which aren't eagerly loaded? (eg It could be populating the BulletinEmailLogRecipients)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestion. I removed the eager load statement and found that only one call to the database was being made. Now I have a different concern/problem. There are other tables referenced in the query that I'm not familiar with. I'm new to the code so it may just be that I hadn't looked up the relationships properly. But anyway , thanks.